# TikZ Poster Turning Blank?

Tags: errors, blank-page

I was using Ti*k*Z to create a conference poster and all of a sudden, the display built into ShareLaTeX displayed a blank green page. I can't seem to attribute the sudden change to a single source.

The code I used is below (used a template). Sorry for the poor formatting:

```
 \documentclass[17pt, a0paper, landscape, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm,
     blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter} %Default values for poster format options.

 \newcommand{\bs}{\textbackslash}   % backslash
 \newcommand{\cmd}[1]{{\bf \color{red}#1}}   % highlights command




\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[all,arc]{xy}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows,automata,arrows,backgrounds,snakes}


 \usetheme{Basic}



 \begin{document}

 \tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position .5 with {{->}}},postaction={decorate}}}


\title{Cosheaf Theoretical Constructions in Networks and Persistent Homology}
    \settitle{\centering{\bfseries \fontsize{65}{78} \sc \@title \par}}
     \maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=20mm]

     \begin{columns}%blocks will be placed into columns
         \column{.25}
         \block[roundedcorners=40]{Introduction}{
            Persistent homology has recently emerged as a powerful technique in topological data analysis for analyzing the emergence and disappearance of topological features throughout a filtered space, shown via persistence diagrams. Additionally, (co)sheaves have proven to be powerful instruments in tracking locally defined data across global systems, resulting in innovative applications to network science. In this paper, we combine the topological results of persistent homology and the quantitative data tracking capabilities of cosheaf theory to develop novel techniques in network data flow analysis. Specifically, we use cosheaf theory to construct persistent homology in a framework geared towards assessing data flow stability in hierarchical recurrent networks (HRNs). We use cosheaves to link topological information about a filtered network encoded in persistence diagrams with data associated locally to the network. From this construction, we use the homology of cosheaves as a framework to study the notion of “persistent data flow errors.” That is, we generalize aspects of persistent homology to analyze the lifetime of local data flow malfunctions. We proceed with several constructions motivated by the persistent homology of filtered topological spaces to fit our network theoretical environment. We conclude with an algorithmic construction of persistence diagrams parameterizing network data flow errors, thus enabling novel applications of statistical methods to study data flow malfunctions. Our results can be applied to analyze data flows in complex systems such as financial, social, and biological networks. 
     }

     \block{Objective}{

     We use cosheaf theory as a framework to develop network-theoretical generalizations of persistent homology to study network data flow malfunctions. These constructions are motivated by the use of statistical techniques to assess properties of persistence diagrams. Originally yielding valuable topological information about a filtered space, our framework enables the extraction of useful information pertaining to complex network data flow from a generalized notion of persistent homology.


     }

     \block{Background}{
     \vspace{4mm}

     \innerblock[\titlecenter, \roundedcorners]{Cosheaves}
     {  Let $\mathscr{X}$ be a topological space and $\mathscr{J}$ an abelian category.
A \textit{$\mathscr{J}$-valued precosheaf} $\mathscr{F}$ on $\mathscr{X}$ is a covariant functor $\mathscr{F}\colon \mathrm{Open}(\mathscr{X}) \to \mathscr{J}$ from the category of open subsets of $\mathscr{X}$ to $\mathscr{J}$. If $U\subset \mathscr{X}$, an element $x\in \mathscr{F}(U)$ is a \textit{cosection} of $\mathscr{F}$ over $U$. For a pair of embedded open subsets $V \subset U \subset \mathscr{X}$, the induced map on the inclusion $\mathscr{F}(V)\to \mathscr{F}(U)$ is called the \textit{corestriction map.} A precosheaf $\mathscr{F}$on $\mathscr{X}$ is a \textit{cosheaf} if for any open $U \subset \mathscr{X}$ and any open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $U$, there is an exact sequence: 
$\bigoplus_i\mathscr{F}(\bigcap_iU_i)  \to \bigoplus_i\mathscr{F}(U_i) \to \mathscr{F}(U) \to 0.$

     }

     \vspace{4mm}
     Essentially, cosheaf theory enables a structured assignment of data to open sets of a topological space. 

      \vspace{6mm}

     \innerblock[\titlecenter, \roundedcorners]{Hierarchical Recurrent Networks}
     { Generally, a Hierarchical Recurrent Network (HRN) can be thought of as the digraph underlying a Hierarchical Recurrent Neural Network. For example the digraph $\mathscr{G}$ below is an HRN: 

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrow{latex}}},
    scale=1.2]

\node[inner sep=1pt, circle, fill=black] (1) at (0,0) [draw] {};
\node[inner sep=1pt, circle, fill=black] (2) at (1,0) [draw] {};
\node[inner sep=1pt, circle, fill=black] (3) at (2,0) [draw] {};
\node[inner sep=1pt, circle, fill=black] (4) at (3,0) [draw] {};
\node[inner sep=1pt, circle, fill=black] (5) at (4,0) [draw] {};
\node[inner sep=1pt, circle, fill=black] (6) at (5,0) [draw] {};
\node[inner sep=1pt, circle, fill=black] (7) at (6,0) [draw] {};
\node[inner sep=1pt, circle, fill=black] (8) at (7,0) [draw] {};

\node[inner sep=1pt, circle, fill=black] (9) at (1.5,1) [draw] {};
\node[inner sep=1pt, circle, fill=black] (10) at (5,1) [draw] {};
\node[inner sep=1pt, circle, fill=black] (11) at (4,1) [draw] {};
\node[inner sep=1pt, circle, fill=black] (12) at (6,1) [draw] {};


\draw[->-]  (1)--(2);
\draw[->-]  (3)--(2);
\draw[->-]  (3)--(4);
\draw[->-]  (4)--(5);
\draw[->-]  (6)--(5);
\draw[->-]  (7)--(6);
\draw[->-]  (7)--(8);

\draw[->-]  (9)--(3);
\draw[->-]  (2)--(9);

\draw[->-]  (5)--(11);
\draw[->-]  (10)--(6);
\draw[->-]  (11)--(10);

\draw[->-]  (12)--(7);
\draw[->-]  (6)--(12);


\end{tikzpicture}


     }



     }



     \column{.25}
         \block{Approach}{
         \vspace{75mm}
         }



         \block{}

         {
             If the default appearance of the title, background, blocks, and notes is not desired, you may change the colors by calling the color style along with a general layout theme with the commands

             \begin{quote}
       \texttt{\bs usecolorpalette}\{{\em color palette}\}\\
                 \texttt{\bs usecolorstyle\{{\em color style}\}}
             \end{quote}
             and
             \begin{quote}
                 \texttt{\bs usetheme\{{\em layout style}\}}
             \end{quote}
             where the color palette and style and layout style are either the name of a custom made or one of the offered predefined choices listed in the manual or the comments of this poster's source.  Individual changes can be made to the style of the  background, title matter, blocks, inner blocks, and notes by using one of the following (along with either a custom-designed style or a predefined style listed in the manual or the comments of this poster's source).  These changes are made with the commands
             \begin{quote}
                 \texttt{\bs usebackgroundstyle[]\{\}, \bs usetitlestyle[]\{\},\\ \bs useblockstyle[]\{\},\bs innerblockstyle[]\{\}, \bs usenotestyle[]\{\}}
             \end{quote}
             Custom styles for these can be made; this is detailed in the manual.
          }




          \column{.25}



          \column{.25}

     \end{columns}



 \end{document}




\endinput
%%
%% End of file `tikzposter-example.tex'.
```

Comment: I changed `\titlecenter` into `titlecenter` (no backslash) and `\roundedcorners` into `roundedcorners=10pt` (two places each); then changed `\block{}<blank line>{` into the correct `\blank{` and got the expected output

Comment: @egreg could you convert your comment into an answer to remove the question from the unanswered ones?

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
 \innerblock[\titlecenter, \roundedcorners]{Cosheaves}
   {Let $\mathscr{X}$ be a topological space and $\mathscr{J}$ an abelian category. [...]}
```

is wrong: there must not be a backslash in front of `titlecenter` and `roundedcorners`; moreover the latter option must be accompanied by a value.

So it should be something like

```
 \innerblock[titlecenter, roundedcorners=10pt]{Cosheaves}
   {Let $\mathscr{X}$ be a topological space and $\mathscr{J}$ an abelian category. [...}}
```

There is another error:

```
\block{}

  {
```

should be

```
\block{}
  {
```

with no intervening blank line.

[image]